# How to edit exif metadata by graphicsmagick command?

Tags: metadata, exif, graphicsmagick, utilities

How to edit or add exif metadata by graphicsmagick command? I've tried the following:

```
gm convert -set EXIF:XPKeywords "bird, sleep, moon" bird.jpg bird2.jpg
```

My command is executing successfully and the image is creating but the exif metadata is not updating.

Comment: Do you get an error? Is an image created (but without EXIF data)? Please add details toyour post by **editing** (not commenting).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do that with GraphicsMagick, and I would suggest `exiv2` like this:

```
exiv2 -M"add Exif.Image.XPKeywords Ascii 'bird,sleep,moon'" image.jpg
```

Then you can view them with `jhead` too:

```
jhead -v image.jpg

JFIF SOI marker: Units: 0 (aspect ratio)  X-density=1 Y-density=1
Exif header 50 bytes long
Exif section in Intel order
(dir has 1 entries)
    Windows-XP keywords = "bird,sleep,moon"
Approximate quality factor for qtable 0: 92 (scale 16.28, var 1.13)
Approximate quality factor for qtable 1: 92 (scale 16.20, var 0.15)
JPEG image is 2000w * 2000h, 3 color components, 8 bits per sample
File name    : image.jpg
File size    : 6968929 bytes
File date    : 2015:10:20 09:23:24
Resolution   : 2000 x 2000
```

Comment: According to 

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html

there is a set, -set <attribute> <value>, option. which is used to add or update named attribute. But there is no example.